# Which Ubuntu distribution version support GLES3

Tags: cobalt

I build the cobalt with platform "linux-x64x11" on Ubuntu as below：

```
$cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.13.0-119-generic (buildd@lcy01-08) (gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) ) #166-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 3 12:18:55 UTC 2017
```

But this Ubuntu can't not support GLES3 because coredump happens, I have to modify the src/starboard/linux/shared/gyp_configuration.gypi file, and substitute "system_gles3" with "system_gles2" to make Cobalt run successfully.

May I ask which linux distribution version support GLES3 perfectly? Otherwise I have to upgrade my opengles library in this Ubuntu.

Wait for help, thanks,

Jenson.

Answer (score 0):

What is your Cobalt version? My up-to-date Cobalt on Linux falls back to GLES2 gracefully.

It looks Ubuntu 17.04 official repository does not have GLES3 yet. If you want to use GLES3, you need to manually install it. Or set the "gl_type" to "system_gles2". I recommend the latter.